# MongoDB does not start after installing first time

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB first time on my Windows 7 machine. I am installing it to default location (c:/).

When I execute the `mongod.exe` first time, I get the message `'the waiting for connections message in the console'`. The documentation of MongoDB asks to connect on another `cmd` prompt and execute `mongod.exe` again.

When I do this I get the following message:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongod.exe
2015-09-04T11:31:23.880+0530 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
2015-09-04T11:31:23.905+0530 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - C:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.

2015-09-04T11:31:23.907+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file:
C:\data\db\mongod.lock errno:32 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.. Is a mo
ngod instance already running?, terminating
2015-09-04T11:31:23.907+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongod.exe
2015-09-04T11:33:52.437+0530 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
2015-09-04T11:33:52.442+0530 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - C:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.

2015-09-04T11:33:52.445+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file:
C:\data\db\mongod.lock errno:32 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.. Is a mo
ngod instance already running?, terminating
2015-09-04T11:33:52.445+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

P.S.: I have created `/data/db` in `C:/`.

Comment: it's not `MangoDB`, it is **MongoDB**

Comment: re install. follow instructions at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: I am using the same document which u mentioned and am stuck on point 3 Connect to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just faced the same issue. I installed the fix, but saw nothing but same error. So that's how I got over it: just create a folder structure in your C catalog like this one: C:\data\db. So it worked for me perfectly. I use Windows 7 x64.

Comment: C:\data\db is already there .On cmd I can see 'C:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty'